# Windows 7 Critical Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

After installing the important updates in my Windows 7 64-bit system, I was casually checking the created restore points. There I've found the restore points with *critical update*. The updates haven't shown any problems during installation.

What does it actually mean? Is it safe to keep those updates or should I revert that?

Comment: Does it correspond to a KB number of a particular update?

Comment: Out of 4 restore points, 3 are with critical updates. And out of them, the recent one contains KB(2670838, 2533623, 2639308 etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete those. They don't take up a critical amount of space - it's basically windows taking precautions before installing windows updates in case something goes wrong.

Basically when it says "Critical update" in the restore points windows is telling you this:

"Hey, I'm installing something important, but I'm going to make a backup of what's going on right now just in case it fails"

Comment: Thanks! Can U give a any link to gt details on it (Microsoft Official link is better, if possible)?

Comment: You can search on the specific KB number.  Microsoft has details on the updates tied to each KB number, you can look at the monthly releases here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/msrc/

Comment: if you type in "http://support.microsoft.com/kb/" and then put the KB number at the end of the URL it'll give you all the info you need to know. Example using one of the KB numbers you posted above. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838